# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\Gamma(n)~n^{1/2}}=1$

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, gamma-function

> Prove $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(x+1/2)}{\Gamma(x)~x^{1/2}}=1.$$

I got this problem from [*Probability and Statistics*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Probability-Statistics-Morris-H-DeGroot/dp/0321709705) by Degroot & Schervish. There is a hint to use Stirling's formula which is stated as:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(2\pi)^\frac{1}{2}x^{x-1/2}e^{-x}}{\Gamma(x)}=1.$$

One way is to reduce the problem by using the hint to

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(x+1/2)~e^x}{(2\pi)^\frac{1}{2}x^{x}}=1.$$

But that did not helped me much. I though about doing the following, but I'm not sure that it is correct:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\Gamma(x+1/2)}{\Gamma(x)~x^{1/2}}&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\int_o^\infty u^{x-1/2}e^{-u}du}{\int_o^\infty u^{x-1}e^{-u}x^{1/2}du}\\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\int_o^k u^{x-1/2}e^{-u}du}{\int_o^k u^{x-1}e^{-u}x^{1/2}du} \right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^{x-1/2}e^{-k}}{k^{x-1}e^{-k}x^{1/2}} \right) \\
&=\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k^{1/2}}{x^{1/2}} \right) \\
&=1.\end{align}$$

I basically tried to apply L'hopital's rule and to play with double limits but I'm really not sure whether this is so to speak 'permissible'. Thus, I would be grateful for any comments or corrections. Please note: the book is relatively at an introductory level so elementary methods should suffice. Thank you!

Comment: For future reference, you can align equalities and such like so:
$$\begin{align} A&=B \\ &=C \\ &\le D\end{align}$$ using `\begin{align} A&=B \\ &=C \\ &\le D\end{align}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wouldn't this be needlessly complicating things? Stirling formula tells you that
$$\Gamma(x+1/2)\sim(2\pi)^{1/2}(x+1/2)^{x}e^{-x-1/2}$$
and that
$$
x^{1/2}\,\Gamma(x)\sim(2\pi)^{1/2}x^{x}e^{-x}
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\Gamma(x+1/2)}{x^{1/2}\,\Gamma(x)}\sim\frac{(2\pi)^{1/2}(x+1/2)^{x}e^{-x-1/2}}{(2\pi)^{1/2}x^{x}e^{-x}}=\left(1+\frac1{2x}\right)^xe^{-1/2}\sim\ldots
$$
To check that you understood what is going on, you might try to compute, for every fixed $a$, the limit of the ratio
$$
\frac{\Gamma(x+a)}{x^a\,\Gamma(x)}.
$$

Comment: excellent, thank you. didn't think about using the Stirling's formula in the way you showed. now I know, thanks again!

Comment: OK. Which limits did you get for the ratios depending on some parameter $a$?

Comment: I got $\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+a/x)^{x+a-1/2}*e^{-a}=1$, right?

Comment: Yep. Well done.